# mysql syntax error (in select query) reports error

Tags: php, mysql

PHP code below reports an error code:

```
$id = $_SESSION['sno'];
$q = mysql_query("select * from messages where seen=0 and to=$id");
if(!$q){die("critical failure: ".mysql_error());}
```

Error reported is:

```
critical failure: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to=1' at line 1
```

'to=1' shows that $_SESSION['sno'] is set to 1

Comment: You should use MySQLi or PDO instead of `mysql_*` functions, which are deprecated. [More information avalible here](http://cz2.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using a [`mysql reserved keyword`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

```
$q = mysql_query("select * from messages where seen=0 and `to`=$id");
```

`TO` is a reserved keyword, surround it with backticks ` to avoid the error

As side n`mysql_*` finction are deprecated, better to switch either to [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and use prepared statements to avoid any risk of `mysql injections`, learn more here [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

`to` is reserved keyword use quote identifier to escape it.

```
mysql_query("select * from messages where `seen`=0 and `to`=$id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ` sign for words like to as this is keywords of My SQL.

So your query looks like

```
$q = mysql_query("select * from messages where seen=0 and `to`=$id");
```